# Display Count Down Timer in label

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to display a countdown timer. I have the start date and end date. I need to     display the remaining time like

> days : hours : minutes : seconds

I got some code from this site, but it will display negative sign when the end date is passed. 
Please any one help me.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void) updateCountdown 
{
    NSString *dateString = @"14-12-2012";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsHours = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    NSDateComponents *componentMint = [calendar components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:now];    
    NSDateComponents *componentSec = [calendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:now];        

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]      initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *componentsDaysDiff = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                        fromDate:now
                                                          toDate:dateFromString
                                                         options:0];

    lblDaysSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",componentsDaysDiff.day];
    lblHouresSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(24-componentsHours.hour)];    
    lblMinitSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(60-componentMint.minute)];  
    lblSecSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(60-componentSec.second)];  
}
```

Comment: So just add an if statement and if it's less than zero invalidate the timer and make it so the label doesn't display anything less than zero?

Comment: thanks, but i want to display images and it details when the timer ends but it will go to negative sign not stopped.

Comment: please give me some sample codes. i am new to iPhone side.

Comment: please post up the code you have used so far an people will then be able to help you

Comment: So if you already have code that changes the images, just add an if statement to check if it will go to zero.  Obviously you have some variables for them already, since you can change the labels, so check that number.  Once it hits zero invalidate the timer and BAM, a working countdown timer.

Comment: please give me the code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(componentsDayDiff.day < 0) { //DOUBLE CHECK THIS WITH NSLOG, I DON'T KNOW WHICH ONE WILL BE NEGATIVE, BUT ONE OF THEM WILL
    [timer invalidate]; //Stop the timer, it's not needed anymore
    //Not _technically_ needed, but a good thing to have, format as you see fit
    lblDaysSetting.text = @"0";
    lblHouresSetting.text = @"0";
    lblMinitSetting.text = @"0";
    lblSecSetting.text = @"0";
    //[self done] //call whatever method you want when the countdown is complete.
} else {
    lblDaysSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",componentsDaysDiff.day];
    lblHouresSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(24-componentsHours.hour)];    
    lblMinitSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(60-componentMint.minute)];  
    lblSecSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(60-componentSec.second)];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to find difference between two dates:

```
NSDate *lastDate = fromDate;
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:lastDate  toDate:todaysDate options:0];
int days = [comps day];
int minute = [comps minute];
int hour = [comps hour];
int second = [comps second];
```

Comment: Can you please share your code ? So I can get idea where is the problem.